# Eliminate indirect left recursion

Tags: compiler-construction

I have the follwing grammer:

```
P -> S P E
P -> x
E -> o
E -> n
S -> -
S -> epsilon
```

Now I have find an indirect left recursion due to the S-> epsilon. But how I could eliminate the left recursion? Or I could I make a direct left recursion out of this?

Comment: You can make direct left recursion by factoring `S` into its only use: `P -> - P  E | P E | x`

Comment: is somethin like this also correct? P -> SxP'   P' -> EP'|epsilon